# Calculate percentage in Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my **Javascript** Multi-Dimensional Arrays, it stores 3 values: NAME, ROUND, No. of Vote

Sample data:

NAME| ROUND| No. of Vote

Evan | **1** | 2

John | **1** | 1

Mary | **1** | 3

Evan | **2** | 4

John | **2** | 1

I want to display the Voting result on screen with percentage (based on ROUND), Just Like that:

ROUND 1

Evan - 2 Votes **(33.3%)**

John - 1 Vote **(16.7%)**

Mary - 3 Votes **(50%)**

ROUND 2

Evan - 4 Votes **(80%)**

John - 1 Vote **(20%)**

Thanks,
Joe

The following is my javascript code:.

```
function rpt_result(){
var temp = '';
var l_temp = '';
var html = '';
var num = obj('remain').value;
var total = 0;
var tmp_round = 0;
html += '<html>';
html += '<head><title>Voting Result</title>';
html += '</head>';
html += '<body>';
html += '<table width="760" align="center"><tr><td align="center"><h2>' + obj('ta_title').value + '</h2></td></tr>';
html += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
html += '<tr><td align="center">Each Round Results</td>';
html += '</table>';
html += '<div id="button" style="width:760px;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;"><input type="button" value="Print" onmouseup="window.print()" style="float:right;" /></div>';
html += '<table width="760" align="center" border="0">';
html += '<tr>'
html += '<td><b><u>Winner:</b></u></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '<tr><td>';
for (i = 0; i < winnerArray.length; i++) {
    temp = winnerArray[i].split('|', 3);
    vote = temp[0];
    name = temp[1];
    round = temp[2];
    html += '(The' + num2Chi(round) + 'Round)　' + name + '　' + vote + 'Votes' + '<br />'; 
}
html += '</td></tr>';
html += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
html += '<tr>'
html += '<td><b><u>Detail Voting Result:</b></u></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '<tr><td>';

for (i = 0; i < wholeArray.length; i++) {
    w_temp = wholeArray[i].split('|', 4);
    w_vote = w_temp[0];
    w_name = w_temp[1];
    w_round = w_temp[2];
        html += '<font color="red">(The' + num2Chi(w_round) + 'Round)　' + w_name + '　' + w_vote + ' Votes </font><br />';
}
html += '</td></tr>';

html += '</table>';
html += '</body>';
html += '</html>';
var x = window.open('', 'printList', "location=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600");
x.document.write(html);
x.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 loops, one to count ALL the votes, and set it into a sum variable, and the other the calculate the percentage of each.